# "Device is offline" after succesfully installing APK

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When trying to debug my app, the installation of the APK works fine, but starting the debugger, gives the error "Device is offline":

```
01/17 15:56:08: Launching app
$ adb push /home/bf/Projects/.../app-full-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/nl.my.app
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/nl.my.app"
Success
APK installed in 3 s 918 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "nl.my.app/nl.my.app.activities.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Device is offline
```

I tried updating the SDK, to no avail. Running the same app on another device works fine.

Also, when launching (in the "Select Deployment Target" screen), it doesn't give me any information, only serial number and `[null]`, while I get full info on other devices (make and model, etc)

Comment: check your cable..

Comment: Maybe you have 2 versions of `adb`? Is your cable faulty/damaged? What's the output of `adb devices` (this prints out the list of connected devices)?

Comment: Try to connect your usb cable to another usb port in your computer.

Comment: `adb devices` gives me the serial number and `device` (nothing more).

Comment: I replaced the cable with a new one. Same issue. It happens always, and immediately (a faulty cable would also give errors on installing the APK).

Comment: try to have a loot at my attached linke, it may help you

Comment: USB debugging enabled on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't resolve the issue itself, but using TCP/IP debugging did work:

```
~$ adb tcpip 5555
~$ adb connect <ipaddr>:5555
```

the device is now shown with all information in the "Select Deployment Target" screen as well.